# Slow render on mobile chrome horizontal and vertical scroll div

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, webkit

I am building a kanban-like board for a project of mine but I am having issues with rendering sometimes on mobile Chrome. There are vertical panels divs that can be scrolled horizontally and inside them there are card-like entries. The problem is that the card entries sometimes disappear or are not rendered until the panel is scrolled vertically.

It is a bit hard to reproduce as it seems it is some kind of rendering optimizations for mobile. Any ideas how to escape it?

I've tested it on mobile.

Here is a video from Chrome Dev tools on desktop: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9THsHAnqS7fZUJXZk9qTHZBN3c/view

Seems that both horizontal and vertical scroll don't play too well together and I'm trying to figure it out for two days now.

```js
$(function () {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    $('.panel').height($(window).height() - $('.panel').offset().top - 20);
  });
  $(window).resize();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 40px auto;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
  padding: 0 10px
}

.panel {
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 600px;
    border: solid 1px #bbb;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 10px;
}

.panel-content {
    padding: 10px;
}

.panel-title {
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
}

.panel-title p {
    margin: 0;
}

.horizontal-scroll {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.cardc .cardc-content {
    padding: 10px;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.cardc {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="horizontal-scroll">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <p>To do</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-content">
            <div class="cardc small">
                <div class="cardc-content">
                  <h4>Hello world</h4>
                  <p>something something</p>
                  <p>something something</p>
                  <p>something something</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <p>Now</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-content">
            <div class="cardc small">
              <div class="cardc-content">
                  <h4>Hello world</h4>
                  <p>something something</p>
                  <p>something something</p>
                  <p>something something</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <p>Done</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-content">
            <div class="cardc small" id="done_tasks">
                <div class="cardc-content">
                  <h4>Hello world</h4>
                  <p>something something</p>
                  <p>something something</p>
                  <p>something something</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```